# Rails Whenever gem cron fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I am running a Rails server that periodically runs a `rake task` using whenever gem and cron.

I can run the `rake task` using these successfully. On my remote server, I am running that as the root. This second attempt also works.

```
     RAILS_ENV=production rake fetch_myitems
     // attempt 1
     //attempt 2
     /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/rails/AniKawaii && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake fetch_animegifs --silent >> log/whenever.log 2>&1'
```

After debugging, this is what I ended up with as the source of error. I understand that this is related to database.yml. However I can deploy to my live production server successfully and calling `RAILS_ENV=production rake fetch_myitems` does not trigger this error so I am confused as to what to do.

```
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

#### Crontab -l

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/rails/AniKawaii && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake fetch_animegifs --silent >> log/whenever.log 2>&1'
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason in `/etc/default/unicorn file` the  `APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD` does not get updated even if I reload nginx along with unicorn.

My fix was to manually override the password in database.yml.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your database.yml file looks something like:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: test-postgres_production
  pool: 5
  username: rails
  password: <%= ENV['PGPASS'] %>
```

Meaning that the password is obtained from an environment variable. Your cronjob should look something like:

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/rails/AniKawaii && RAILS_ENV=production PGPASS=your_database_password_here bundle exec rake fetch_animegifs --silent >> log/whenever.log 2>&1'
```

Hope that sorts you.

Comment: Even though this will work, is it safe to have the pass in cron?

Comment: cron is still safer than having it in the repository